# PHP: Delete row from MySQL where time passed expiration date and id not equal to 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($rex)){
if($data['expiry']!=null){
     $id = $data['id'];
                        $del = "DELETE FROM $itemlist (WHERE id = $id) AND (STR_TO_DATE(expiry,'%a %d-%M-%Y%H:%i:%s')<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $del)) {
continue;
}
```

This is what I've tried so far, but nothing is working; None of the rows get deleted. I stored the expiration date in a `VARCHAR` as something like Mon 27-Mar-2017 23:11:50 and made the column nullable. I don't want to do anything to rows with an id = 1 or rows that have a null expiration date. What am I missing? If I delete it, can I then rearrange `id` which is an auto-increment start from id 2 without deleting id 1? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STR_TO_DATE function will return null, when you use it like this - `(STR_TO_DATE(expiry,'%a %d-%M-%Y%H:%i:%s')` for your expiry date format.

Can you try like this ?

```
if($data['expiry']!=null) {
    $id = $data['id'];
    $expiry_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['expiry']));
    $del = "DELETE FROM $itemlist WHERE id = $id AND $expiry_date<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $del)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad parenthesis
Change `(WHERE id= $id` change that to WHERE (id = $id

Comment: Oh no it doesn't work! It's not delete the null but delete all the non null even the expiry date didn't reach yet.

Comment: Even if it doesn't work, I'm telling you that with that `(WHERE` in there the code will bomb out.  If you have  other errors in the `STR_TO_DATE` section, that cannot be answered from a small snippet like this.  For example, you are missing another pair of  `}` at the end of the program.